# How not to cache only a piece of code of my template in django

Tags: python, django, caching, django-templates

Under django v. 1.4.

The problem:

Since my template is rendered by this view which will be totally stored in cache:

```
@cache_page(60*60*24)
def index(request):
    foo_form = FooForm()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'foo_form': foo_form
    })
    # An entire page is rendered
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=context)
```

In my template I have an if statement which checks whether user is authenticate:

```
...
<li>
    {%  if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="login">Enter</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="" class="login" data-target="#login_modal" data-tggle="modal">Enter</a>
    {% endif %}

</li>
...
```

There is a modal that's activated by a button "Enter" which should be displayed when there's no user logged, otherwise the user is redirected to the system when the "Enter" button is clicked.

The question: Is there a way to ignore only that piece of code from my template to be not cached? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Template fragment caching:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %}
    .. sidebar for logged in user ..
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: Hello there buddy! How would I apply that in my code? I tested this Template fragment caching in my code, but I don't know if it was totally correct. And as the Django docs describes templ fragment caching, it is the same as storing in cache using the decorator as I did in my view. So, there should exist some way to avoid caching in certain areas of your code, but that's more like a secrete which no one wants to share.

Comment: Here's an evergreen link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to display the user authentication template, so caching wont affect your template.

`<li>`

```
`{%  if user.is_authenticated %}`
   ` <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="login">Enter</a>`
`{% else %}`
    `<a href="" class="login" data-target="#login_modal" data-tggle="modal">Enter</a>`
```

`{% endif %}`

`</li>`